# Oracle Select and Group By

Tags: oracle, subquery, group

I have the below table.

```
create table cricket(team1 varchar2(22),team2 varchar2(22));

select * from cricket
```

Team1  Team2

```
INDIA  SL
SL    AUS
SA    ENG
ENG   NZ
AUS   INDIA
```

in the above table i want to  display the count of teams
played.
for example

```
India 2
SL    1
Sa    1
Eng   2
Aus   2
```

Comment: Okay, but just "wanting" doen't produce anything. Please describe what you have tried so far and what is your current issue. And describe in general words how to get your desired output from the sample data (which is the key to start with a query composition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `UNION ALL` the two columns, then count over that:

```sql
WITH ALL_TEAMS AS (
    SELECT TEAM1 AS TEAM FROM CRICKET
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT TEAM2 FROM CRICKET
)
SELECT 
    TEAM, 
    COUNT(1) AS NUMBER_OF_PLAYS
FROM ALL_TEAMS
GROUP BY TEAM
```